# Decibel levels of animals

Tags: measurements

Im looking for some kind of list with DBSPL Levels of different animals. How high they shout, scream or sings. I've got a feeling there's something like that out there somewhere but google isn't my friend right now and aI hope that you might be. Im looking for an extensive list of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

That's probably going to be tough to find. The only things I've spotted recently were articles discussing the loudest insects (which are some of the loudest creatures on the planet), and I could only say those were in the last year...specific articles, sources and dates are completely lost to me. That might be a place to restart your google search though.

**Edit:**
Here's a good start point: [NatGeo article](http://news.nationalgeographic.com/news/2011/07/pictures/110711-loudest-animals-water-boatman-singing-genitals/)

Comment: Thank! But as you said, it's hard to find. Im building a ambience generator and I use the sounds natural DB so that they'll have the same dynamic difference as in real life. But it seems like I have to go out there and measure it myself.